# What is the proper SWI statement to print integers in assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

Im trying to make a while loop in assembly but my SWI statement to get the numbers to "print" is giving me an error.

```
.text
    mov r1, #10
    mov r2, #1
    b L2

L3:
    SWI 0x6b

    sub r1,r1,#-1

L2:
    cmp r1, r2
    bgt L3
```

The error occurs once i get to the SWI 0x6b and the exact error message is "Unimplemented SWI code.

Comment: You forgot to specify what OS/environment.

Comment: Most modern systems put the call number in `r7` instead of making the kernel disassemble backwards from the saved PC value to fetch the immediate from the SWI instruction.  For some reason ARM doesn't actually put the interrupt code anywhere the kernel can easily find it.

Comment: system calls are defined by the operating system which operating system is this, and then from there what is the system calling convention and then which is the call for the function in question?

Comment: @Jester Sorry i am on windows 10 and im using armsim 2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

You may have encountered multiple problems here:

1. ARMSim v2.1 is supposed to be honoring a [subset](https://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~nigelh/ARMSim-V2.1/AngelInstructions.pdf) of the [Angel/Semihosting interface](https://static.docs.arm.com/100863/0200/semihosting.pdf).
   That means that r0 should contain a function number, r1 a pointer to a parameter block, and that the SWI number to be used shall be `0x123456`, as in  `swi 0x123456`, and your program is obviously not compliant.
2. If you want to display a digit, you have to convert this digit into a representation of this digit that can be displayed. For example, if register r1 does contain #10, the value shall be processed so that value #'A' will be displayed. If r1 does contain a value in the range 0..9, the shall be processed so that a value in the #'0'..#'9' will be displayed.
3. The ARMSim v2.1 I experimented with on my Lubuntu 19.10 system failed executing `swi 0x123456`, and I got the same infamous error message, `"Unimplemented SWI code."` you got. Even more, the program `Angel_print_int.s`, contained in the [ARMSim examples archive file](https://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~nigelh/ARMSim-V2.1/TestFiles.zip), failed to execute as well.

At this stage, I would assume ARMSim v2.1 is not working as expected, and I switched to an [online simulator](https://cpulator.01xz.net/?sys=arm-de1soc) supporting the [Terasic DE1-SoC Board](https://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&No=836). The emulation does support a [JTAG-UART device](http://www-ug.eecg.toronto.edu/msl/nios_devices/dev_jtaguart.html) suitable for displaying characters.

You program was modified so that it would be able to display hexadecimal representations of values in range 1..10 using the emulated JTAG-UART device;

```
.global _start
.text
_start:
    mov r1, #10
    mov r2, #1
    // http://www-ug.eecg.toronto.edu/msl/nios_devices/dev_jtaguart.html
    ldr r3, =0xFF201000
    b L2

L3:
    mov r0, r1
    // convert value contained in r1 into a displayable hexadecimal digit
    cmp r0,#9
    bgt hex
dec:
    add r0,#'0'
    b continue
hex:
    add r0,#'A' - 10
continue:
    strb r0, [r3]

    sub r1,r1,#1

L2:
    cmp r1, r2
    bge L3
    mov r0, #'0'
done:
    b done
```

Compiling/loading/executing the program resulted in the following chraracters being displayed in the JTAG UART Windows ah the right:

```
A987654321
```

An alternative to using this emulator would be to use [QEMU for Windows](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/w64/) and [arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/9.2-2019.12/binrel/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz?revision=11ead78b-0442-489c-bd97-f18db1866f30&la=en&hash=5BCB8EE533636CF34FF99AB46CCB60CE11E4F1E1). I could provide a working procedure/example in the case you would be interested.

I hope this helped.